# MobSF unable to install on windows 11

Tags: python, windows

I have a question regarding installation of MobSF on my windows 11. its been countless times i tried without any luck.

i appreciate the expert here to point out what is my problems.I have downloaded latest MobSF from git

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF>setup
[INSTALL] Checking for Python version 3.8+
[INSTALL] Found Python 3.9.5
[INSTALL] Found pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (21.1.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-23.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 261 kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.1.1
Successfully installed pip-23.1.2
[INSTALL] Found OpenSSL executable
[INSTALL] Found Visual Studio Build Tools
[INSTALL] Creating venv
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\user\documents\mobile-security-framework-mobsf\venv\lib\site-packages (21.1.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-23.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.1 MB 384 kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.1.1
    Uninstalling pip-21.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.1.1
Successfully installed pip-23.1.2
[INSTALL] Installing Requirements
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 64.5/64.5 kB 53.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.40.0
Ignoring gunicorn: markers 'platform_system != "Windows"' don't match your environment
Collecting Django>=3.1.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading Django-4.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 8.0/8.0 MB 2.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting lxml>=4.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading lxml-4.9.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 3.9/3.9 MB 524.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting rsa>=4.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading rsa-4.9-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting biplist>=1.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading biplist-1.0.3.tar.gz (21 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting requests>=2.25.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 62.6/62.6 kB 418.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting bs4>=0.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting colorlog>=4.7.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading colorlog-6.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting macholib>=1.14 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading macholib-1.16.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting whitenoise>=5.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Downloading whitenoise-6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting waitress>=1.4.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Downloading waitress-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 57.7/57.7 kB 1.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting psutil>=5.8.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Downloading psutil-5.9.5-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (255 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 255.1/255.1 kB 1.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting shelljob>=0.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Downloading shelljob-0.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (9.9 kB)
Collecting asn1crypto>=1.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Downloading asn1crypto-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (105 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 105.0/105.0 kB 1.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting oscrypto>=1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Downloading oscrypto-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 194.6/194.6 kB 2.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting distro>=1.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Downloading distro-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting IP2Location==8.9.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Downloading IP2Location-8.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting lief>=0.12.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
  Downloading lief-0.13.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (3.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 3.1/3.1 MB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting http-tools>=2.1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
  Downloading http-tools-2.1.1.tar.gz (550 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 550.3/550.3 kB 3.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting libsast>=1.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
  Downloading libsast-1.5.2.tar.gz (36 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pdfkit>=0.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
  Downloading pdfkit-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting google-play-scraper>=0.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
  Downloading google_play_scraper-1.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting androguard==3.4.0a1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading androguard-3.4.0a1-py3-none-any.whl (918 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 918.1/918.1 kB 668.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting apkid==2.1.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
  Downloading apkid-2.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (116 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 116.6/116.6 kB 3.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting quark-engine==22.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25))
  Downloading quark_engine-22.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 97.6/97.6 kB 1.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting frida==15.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 26))
  Downloading frida-15.2.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting tldextract==3.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 27))
  Downloading tldextract-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 93.9/93.9 kB 1.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting openstep-parser==1.5.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 28))
  Downloading openstep_parser-1.5.4-py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Collecting svgutils==0.3.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 29))
  Downloading svgutils-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting ruamel.yaml==0.16.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 31))
  Downloading ruamel.yaml-0.16.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 111.9/111.9 kB 1.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting click==8.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 32))
  Downloading click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 97.4/97.4 kB 1.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting decorator==4.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 33))
  Downloading decorator-4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.6.0 (from Django>=3.1.5->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading asgiref-3.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.3.1 (from Django>=3.1.5->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading sqlparse-0.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 41.2/41.2 kB 998.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tzdata; sys_platform == "win32" (from Django>=3.1.5->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading tzdata-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (341 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 341.8/341.8 kB 1.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.3 (from rsa>=4.7->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading pyasn1-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 83.9/83.9 kB 1.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests>=2.25.1->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (97 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 97.1/97.1 kB 2.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.25.1->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 61.5/61.5 kB 1.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.25.1->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading urllib3-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (123 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 123.2/123.2 kB 904.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.25.1->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading certifi-2023.5.7-py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 157.0/157.0 kB 1.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting beautifulsoup4 (from bs4>=0.0.1->-r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (142 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 143.0/143.0 kB 1.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting colorama; sys_platform == "win32" (from colorlog>=4.7.2->-r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting altgraph>=0.17 (from macholib>=1.14->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading altgraph-0.17.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting mitmproxy==6.0.2 (from http-tools>=2.1.1->-r requirements.txt (line 19))
  Downloading mitmproxy-6.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 1.1/1.1 MB 2.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting markupsafe==2.0.1 (from http-tools>=2.1.1->-r requirements.txt (line 19))
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (14 kB)
Collecting pyyaml>=6.0 (from libsast>=1.5.1->-r requirements.txt (line 20))
  Downloading PyYAML-6.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (151 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 151.6/151.6 kB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting networkx>=2.2 (from androguard==3.4.0a1->-r requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading networkx-3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pygments>=2.3.1 (from androguard==3.4.0a1->-r requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading Pygments-2.15.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 1.1/1.1 MB 5.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting matplotlib>=3.0.2 (from androguard==3.4.0a1->-r requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading matplotlib-3.7.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (7.6 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 7.6/7.6 MB 5.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pydot>=1.4.1 (from androguard==3.4.0a1->-r requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading pydot-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting ipython>=5.0.0 (from androguard==3.4.0a1->-r requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading ipython-8.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (798 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 798.7/798.7 kB 5.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting yara-python-dex>=1.0.1 (from apkid==2.1.4->-r requirements.txt (line 24))
  Downloading yara_python_dex-1.0.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (130 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 130.2/130.2 kB 8.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting prettytable>=1.0.0 (from quark-engine==22.10.1->-r requirements.txt (line 25))
  Downloading prettytable-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting tqdm (from quark-engine==22.10.1->-r requirements.txt (line 25))
  Downloading tqdm-4.65.0-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 77.1/77.1 kB 4.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting graphviz (from quark-engine==22.10.1->-r requirements.txt (line 25))
  Downloading graphviz-0.20.1-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 47.0/47.0 kB 2.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pandas (from quark-engine==22.10.1->-r requirements.txt (line 25))
  Downloading pandas-2.0.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (10.7 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 10.7/10.7 MB 4.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.19 (from quark-engine==22.10.1->-r requirements.txt (line 25))
  Downloading prompt_toolkit-3.0.19-py3-none-any.whl (368 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 368.4/368.4 kB 5.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting plotly (from quark-engine==22.10.1->-r requirements.txt (line 25))
  Downloading plotly-5.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15.3 MB)
     ----------------------------- ---------- 11.3/15.3 MB 32.1 kB/s eta 0:02:06
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 561, in read
    data = self._fp_read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 527, in _fp_read
    return self._fp.read(amt) if amt is not None else self._fp.read()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 455, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 499, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 377, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 185, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 509, in _resolve_one
    dist = self._get_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 462, in _get_dist_for
    dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 516, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 587, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 166, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 107, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 147, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 53, in _rich_progress_bar
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 622, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 587, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
[INSTALL] Clean Up
=======================MobSF Clean Script for Windows=======================
Running this script will delete the Scan database, all files uploaded and generated.
C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\scripts
Deleting all uploads
Deleting all downloads
Deleting Static Analyzer migrations
Deleting Dynamic Analyzer migrations
Deleting MobSF migrations
Deleting temp and log files
Deleting Scan database
Deleting Secret file
Deleting Previous setup files
Deleting MobSF data directory: "C:\Users\User\.MobSF"
Done
[INSTALL] Migrating Database
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
Download and Install wkhtmltopdf for PDF Report Generation - https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
[INSTALL] Installation Complete
[ERROR] Installation Failed!
Please ensure that all the requirements mentioned in documentation are installed before you run setup script.
Scroll up to see any installation errors.

The 'decorator==4.4.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Ive tried git clone
reinstall python to 3.9.5
put the environment variables for python

Comment: That sounds like a question for the MobSF folks first, not Stackoverflow (yet)? Did you check their issue tracker already, and if there was nothing relating to your problem, did you post a bug report? (And if so, [remember to say so](/help/how-to-ask) in your post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:
`The 'decorator==4.4.2' distribution was not found`

So have you tried simply running `pip install decorator==4.4.2`? According to this [github issue](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/issues/1621), installing the missing package fixed a similar problem.